# facebook is not loading inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, iframe

I am using iframe to display a website inside my iframe as

```
<iframe id="viewCampaign" frameborder="0" class="viewCampaign"
    style="height: 100% !important;width: 100% !important;" src="@if(isset($campMetaData->page_url)){{$campMetaData->page_url}}@endif">
</iframe>
```

I wondered all other website is loading properly inside iframe, but the facebook not getting loaded. Also the websites which uses "https://" port not getting loaded in my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has this header on the response

```
x-frame-options:DENY
```

It prevents loading the response on an iframe.